# awk copying columns with multiple conditions

Tags: awk, conditional-statements

I'm trying to compare the columns in two different files (1st from `proba2.dat` with 2nd from `proba1.dat`), ex

```
proba1.dat
1 -3.56
2 -3.40
3 -3.12
4 -3.04
5 -3.11
6 -3.22

proba2.dat
-3.00 0.080
-3.05 0.084
-3.10 0.086
-3.15 0.097
-3.20 0.104
-3.25 0.160
-3.30 0.230
-3.35 0.340
-3.40 0.259
-3.45 0.123
-3.50 0.033
-3.55 0.030
-3.60 0.012
```

If they match inside the interval of **0.05**, then I want to add the 3rd column to the `proba1.dat` with the values of the 2nd column from `proba2.dat`, so that I get

```
proba3.dat
1 -3.56 0.030
2 -3.40 0.259
3 -3.12 0.086
4 -3.04 0.084
5 -3.11 0.086
6 -3.22 0.104
```

I tried with

```
awk 'FNR == NR { k[$2] = 1; next } { if (k[$1] <= 1+0.025 && k[$1] >= 1-0.025) { print $0 } }' \proba1.dat proba2.dat > proba3.dat
```

but it only prints the values which match exactly

```
-3.40 0.259
```

and also there is no 1st column from `proba1.dat`. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: You need to match *every* line from `proba2.dat` with *every* line from `proba1.dat`? You'll need a loop for that. You'll also want to save the entire input line in your awk script under the column value (hopefully they are unique) so you can get them back. It might make sense to process the second file first for this.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That worked for me:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2} 
     FNR!=NR{for(i in a){if($2>=i-0.025&&$2<=i+0.025){$3=a[i];print;next}}}' \
       proba2.dat proba1.dat
```

- `FNR==NR` applies only on the first file `proba2.dat`

  - `a[$1]=$2` fills an array `a` with the first field as index and the second as values.
- `FNR!=NR` applies only on the second file `proba1.dat`

  - `for(i in a)` loops trough the prevously created array `a`.
  - `if($2>=i-0.025&&$2<=i+0.025` if the values is in range of 0.05
  - `$3=a[i]` set the "new" third field to that value where the index is in that range.
  - `print;next` print the new line and continue to the next line.

Comment: note you can also say `FNR==NR {things; next}` so you then don't have to say `FNR!=NR` and simply say `{for (i in a) ...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write a little function to round the numbers to the closest 5:

```
function myround(val) {
    n=int(val*100)
    nearest=sprintf("%.0f", n/5)
    near5=nearest*5
    return sprintf("%.2f", near5/100)
}
```

Then, it is a matter to loop through the 2nd file storing its values and then looping through the 1st one looking for the closest value:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} {print $0, a[myround($2)]}' f2 f1
```

All together:

```
awk 'function myround(val) {
       n=int(val*100)
       nearest=sprintf("%.0f", n/5)
       near5=nearest*5
       return sprintf("%.2f", near5/100)
}
FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} {print $0, a[myround($2)]}' f2 f1
```

It returns:

```
1 -3.56 0.030
2 -3.40 0.259
3 -3.12 0.086
4 -3.04 0.084
5 -3.11 0.086
6 -3.22 0.104
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{b=$2;sub(".$",/[0-4]$/?"0":"5");print $1,b,a[$2]}' proba2.dat proba1.dat
1 -3.56 0.030
2 -3.40 0.259
3 -3.12 0.086
4 -3.04 0.080
5 -3.11 0.086
6 -3.22 0.104
```

Answer (score 0):

reading files in logical order

```
awk 'FNR==NR{L[++s]=$0;M[s]=$2;next}{for(i=1;i<=s;i++)if(sqrt(($1-M[i])^2)<=0.025)L[i]=L[i] " " $2}END{for(i=1;i<=s;i++)print L[i]}' proba1.dat proba2.dat > proba3.dat
```

reading files in opposite order

```
awk 'FNR==NR{V[$1]=$2;next}{for(v in V)if(sqrt(($2-v)^2)<=0.025){print $0 " " V[v];next}print}' proba2.dat proba1.dat > proba3.dat
```

In both version, the line from proba1.dat is printed without extra information if not correspondence found in proba2.dat